# No matching issues found in the sonarqube 3.7.4

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm working in the sonarqube 3.7.4. I analysed my java project and it clearly showing me the number of issues with the count. But while clicking the issues it results in "No matching issues found".

[image]

Please provide me the suggestion to fix the issues

Comment: Hi Folks, Please help to fix the issues. It's urgent.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to the latest LTS version of SonarQube : 4.5.6